# Dissapearing caret in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, 18.04, intellij

Whenever I cancel out of any of the popup menus (for example Recent files dialog or similar), the caret in the editor disappears. I need to click somewhere in the editor to get it back.

I am using keyboard shortcuts mainly using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>. For example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> to *Enter action* dialog.

I then press <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to get out of the popup dialog.

Does anyone have any idea of what this could be? Not sure if it is a Gnome, Ubuntu or Idea problem.

**Example**
[image]

**System details**

- Ubuntu 18.04 w. Gnome
- IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.4 (Community Edition)
  Build #IC-181.5087.20, built on May 17, 2018
  JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b39 amd64
  JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
  Linux 4.15.0-22-generic

Comment: Have you tried searching for a bug report on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/? https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-147626 might be related. If you don't find anything, I would recommend opening an issue there.

Comment: Issue opened here:   https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-192741#u=1527362694108

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an IntelliJ Idea regression bug and will be fixed in 2018.1.5.

See issue here:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-191839